# ReSharper Possible InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, resharper

```
public class BloodPressure {
    public Int16? Diastolic { get; set; }

    private Boolean IsValid {
        get {
            var valid = false;

            if (this.Diastolic.HasValue && this.Systolic.HasValue) {
                if ((this.Diastolic.Value >= 0) && (this.Systolic.Value >= 0)) {
                    valid = true;
                }
            }

            return (valid);
        }
    }

    public Int16? Systolic { get; set; }

    public override String ToString() {
        var result = "";

        if (this.IsValid) {
            result = this.Systolic.Value.ToString("0") + "/" + this.Diastolic.Value.ToString("0");
        }
        else {
            result = null;
        }

        return (result);
    }
}
```

This is the line ReSharper complains about:

```
result = this.Systolic.Value.ToString("0") + "/" + this.Diastolic.Value.ToString("0");
```

Since I'm calling my validation logic beforehand I can be sure that both Systolic and Diastolic will have values I can use. Is ReSharper not seeing that, or is it complaining about something else?

Interestingly, it doesn't have a problem with this section:

```
if ((this.Diastolic.Value >= 0) && (this.Systolic.Value >= 0)) {
    valid = true;
}
```

Comment: There are frequent situations when one calls validation methods like IsNotNull(), IsValid() before manipulating a value.
Resharper has an excellent concept of annotation attributes (i.e. NotNull). It would be a good idea for Jetbrains to go further and implement ones like EnsuresNotNull("paramName"), EnsuresNotNull("propertyName"), EnsuresNotNull("fieldName"), it will give us an opportunity to get rid of wornings like this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ReSharpers detection capabilities of stuff like this has its boundaries. ReSharper doesn't recognize that the call to `this.IsValid` basically is equivalent to `this.Diastolic.HasValue && this.Systolic.HasValue` with regards to that problem, i.e. ReSharper looks for those checks only in the same method/property.

Comment: Since some of my clients grade us on number of ReSharper issues, how would you suggest I cleanly resolve this? I'd like to keep the `IsValid` property so that the validating logic in `ToString()` doesn't get so nasty.

Comment: First verify that replacing `IsValid` with the code inside `IsValid` really removes that warning. If so, just make ReSharper ignore this particular warning, so there is no ReSharper issue anymore ;-) *(Grading code on number of ReSharper issues is nonsense)*

Comment: Moving the `IsValid` logic into `ToString()` does in fact get rid of the warning. Based on my previous statement I'll probably just leave it this way. It sure is ugly.